# Including routes from other files

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I wrote the following code and it works, but is there a better way to include the files rather than evaling the contents of the file? I tried to just call require but then the files processed in the context of mainObj.

Ideas?

```
module ActionDispatch
  module Routing
    class Mapper
      def include_routes(file)
        file = File.new("#{Rails.root}/config/routes/#{file}.rb", "r")
        buffer = ""
        while (line = file.gets)
          buffer += line
        end
        file.close

        eval(buffer)

      end
    end
  end
end
```

an individual file looks like this

```
resources :brands do
  collection do
    post :sort
    get :published
    get :unpublished
    get :deleted
  end
  member do
    get :notes
    get :undelete
    get :delete
    post :move_node
    get :get_node_children
  end
  resources :notes, :only => [:new, :create]
end
get "brands/filter/:type" => "brands#filter", :as => 'filter_brands'
```

routes file looks like this

```
KohcmsV4::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  mount_languages

  namespace :admin do

    root :to => 'admin#index'

    include_routes "admin/media"
    include_routes "admin/videos"
    include_routes "admin/roles"
    include_routes "admin/users"
    include_routes "admin/images"
    include_routes "admin/videos"

    language_scope do  

      include_routes "admin/pages"
      include_routes "admin/brands"
      include_routes "admin/pcategories"
      include_routes "admin/products"
      include_routes "admin/procedures"
      include_routes "admin/sections"

    end
  end

  root :to => 'application#index'
  #match '*not_found', to: 'errors#error_404'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `routes.rb` you could do something like the following:

```
Dir["#{Rails.root}/config/routes/*.rb"].each do |route_file|
  load route_file
end
```

If you do use the `load` approach, you will need to change your sub routing files to look like this:

```
KohcmsV4::Application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
    resources :brands do
      collection do
      post :sort
      get :published
      get :unpublished
      get :deleted
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: this may work i think load is what i was missing here. i dont want to load all the files in there, more selectively let me try load in my custom funciton and if thats the case i will make this accepted.

Comment: load still results in undefined method `resources' for main:Object

Comment: `load` may not work out for you if you want to partially nest the routes in the main `routes.rb` file. In order for load to work you would need each of your sub route files to be a full route. Sorry. May be steering you the wrong way here. Expanded answer to include example.

Comment: You may be able to accomplish more of what you are looking for with an approach more like what is taken here: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/router.rb

Comment: ahh thats what i was missing ;)